# Camunda 8/Zeebe Exporter save record to PostgreSQL using Spring

Tags: camunda, exporter, zeebe

I want to save UserTask information to PostgreSQL so that I can complete the UserTask using JobKey from my application. To achieve this I am planning to save the JobRecords using the Exporter class to DB. How can we make the Exporter class save to PostgreSQL using Spring?
I am using Zeebe Broker 8.x & Java 17.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned also on the Camunda forum, the exporter needs to implement an interface and will be directly called by the broker. So it won't run as a spring boot application.
See here for further information
https://forum.camunda.io/t/zeebe-exporter-postgresql/48507/2